# JQuery - Call Same Page but with Different Model data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Imagine this is in your controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(string SomeData = null)
{
    return View("Index", SomeData);
}
```

Inside Index.cshtml is this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model, new { Id = "SomeData", Name = "SomeData" })
```

When the User navigates to Index, SomeData will of course be null.

Once loaded, the User can click a button that executes an ajax call that brings up a Bootstrap Modal Dialog on success.  On close of the Modal Dialog I want to refresh the page, but this time with some Data from the Modal Dialog (Index didn't have that data before, when first loaded):

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Test/Index',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            SomeData: 'abcdef'
        },
        success: function (responseData, status, responseObj) {
            console.log(responseData, status, responseObj);
        },
        async: false
    });
```

Here's what I notice, my breakpoint doesn't even get hit.  Ever.  Yet, the console tells me that my ajax call is successful.  And that's right, because I messed around with throwing exceptions and changing return codes, and it all worked right - I just never get my breakpoint hit.

On success, the page never refreshes.  It's as if nothing happens.  So something else needs to be done.

After the Modal Dialog closes, how do I get this same page updated with the new Model data?  I need the page to refresh because of a Grid that I'm using.  So it's not a matter of just setting the hidden field and being happy.  I need the hidden field set for the page load, so that in an OnDataBound event I know to do something specific that I wouldn't do.

I mean, possibly I'm overthinking it.  On return from the Modal Dialog, I suppose I could just do this (instead of another ajax call):

```
location.href = "/Test/Index?SomeData=abcdef"
```

And that all works fine.

Thank you.

Comment: where did you set your breakpoint exactly?

Comment: P.S. As an aside, are you aware that a) `async: false` is deprecated due to the poor user experience (the browser UI is locked during requests) and b) you don't need it here, because you're handling the response correctly using a callback.

Comment: "On success, the page never refreshes. It's as if nothing happens."...well quite. The whole point of AJAX is to _stay on the same page_. Do you see anything logged in your Console on success? That would tell you if it's working. If you want anything else to happen, you'll have to write some JavaScript to make it happen. Returning a View from an action called by AJAX doesn't make a lot of sense, since you don't want to inject an entire view into another view...it would make more sense to return a Partial View, or some JSON data.

Comment: breakpoint - I set it in the Controller index function, right at the return.

Comment: well unless you're not running in debug mode or something, you should see it get hit. Perhaps you've got the wrong build config set. That or the AJAX call to that endpoint is not actually being executed.

Comment: I'm somewhat aware about async:false.  But I also didn't originally write this code - and our code is littered with it!  And I do agree I don't need it here, and didn't have it here, until I started mucking around.

Comment: breakpoint #2.  I'm telling you it's odd.  I'm definitely in debug mode.  I've never seen something like this before.  First time I've had this issue.

Comment: re: as if nothing happens ... I do agree that I need to do something with the responseData.  For haha's I tried something like $(this).html(responseData).  But that was just trying something without a complete understanding.

Comment: well it's hard to be sure what the breakpoint issue is without seeing your environment. But in terms of the page structure, I'm not convinced the flow is logical...what exactly do you need the ajax call for? You mention executing the AJAX, and then bringing up a dialog when the AJAX succeeds, but you don't need AJAX to display a dialog (unless it will be displaying extra data fetched from the server during the AJAX request). Also, is that referring to a different AJAX call than the one shown above? Because what you've shown doesn't display a dialog. It's a bit confusing...

Comment: The ajax call for the Modal dialog seems fine to me.  A button is clicked, we make an ajax call to a controller action which returns a partial view.  With that partialview we load it into the body of the modal dialog and show the dialog.

Comment: On return of the Modal Dialog (they can press OK or cancel), we check for OK.  If it's OK, I want that page I'm on reloaded but with the new data returned from the dialog.

Comment: I'm probably overthinking it, and I can just do this: location.href = "/Test/Index?SomeData=abcdef"

Comment: Right I see, didn't realise it was loading the dialog via a partial. That's fine then. But yeah if you need to reload the whole page then location.href is the way to go. If you wanted to refresh your grid via Ajax then the grid code would need to be in a partial view as well, similar to the dialog

Comment: You should answer the question, so I can give you a green checkmark!  I really appreciate that you were around to talk this out with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to reload the whole page then `location.href` is the way to go.

If you wanted to refresh your grid via Ajax then the grid code would need to be in a partial view as well, similar to your modal dialog.